# How can I keep updating a JLabel in ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlabel

There are two buttons in GUI: "Go" and "Stop". There is also a JLabel "trainInfoDetail". When "Go" is clicked, how do I let the "speed" in JLabel update once per second while the "Stop" button is still listening and always really to terminate the loop? My program, while looping, seems to stack in this loop and disables "Stop" button until it finishes.

```
myButton1 = new JButton("Go!",icon1);
myButton2 = new JButton("Stop!",icon2);
HandlerClass onClick = new HandlerClass();
myButton1.addActionListener(onClick);
myButton2.addActionListener(onClick);

private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
    //overwriting
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long now;
        String caller = event.getActionCommand();
        if(caller.equals("Go!")){
            while(speed < 100){
                now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if((now - startTime) >= 1000){
                    speed += 10;
                    trainInfoDetail.setText("Speed: "+speed+" mph");
                    startTime = now;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (caller.equals("Stop!")){
            speed = 0;
            trainInfoDetail.setText("Speed: "+speed+" mph");
        }
    }
}
```

after using Timer:

```
public class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
    //overwriting
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String caller = event.getActionCommand();
        TimeClass tc = new TimeClass(caller);
        timer = new Timer(1000, tc);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        timer.start();
    }
}

public class TimeClass implements ActionListener{
    String caller;

    public TimeClass(String caller){
        this.caller=caller;
    }
    //overwriting
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(caller.equals("Go!")){
            speed += 10;
            trainInfoDetail.setText("Speed: "+speed+" mph");        
        }
        else if (caller.equals("Stop!")){
            timer.stop();
        }
        else{
            timer.stop();
            //return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, use a Swing `Timer`.  See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Basically, you can setup the `Timer` to tick every second (or whatever interval you need) and update the state/variables and UI safely, without blocking the UI or violating the thread rules of Swing and you can stop the `Timer` in your "stop" button simply by calling `Timer`'s `stop` method

You should also have a look [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Thank you! That works, but Timer never stops. I update the new code in the question. Can you please take a look and tell me why?

Comment: Personally I'd use `((Timer)e.getSource()).stop()`

Comment: Problem solved by moving everything that happens after clicking "Stop" up one level into the HandlerClass. Again, thank you!